# Android Video Streaming: AsyncTask or UI thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, video-streaming

I'm doing a video streaming project. I have two alternatives:

1. perform myVidoeURI.Prepare() method and play streaming video, both in an AsyncTask.
2. perform myVideoURI.PrepareAsync() method and then play the movie in the UI thread.

What's your decision? support your choice please.

Comment: Go for 1. Do network tasks in ui thread.

Comment: @abid: maybe I'm not clear in option 1, I mean do the prepare() in AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2):

Network operation should be performed on a background thread, instead of main/UI Thread.

Option 1 offers no benefit over Option 2. Even with option 1, video playback needs to be done on UI thread only. Using prepareAsync will free you from handling lifecyle of an AsyncTask.

Go for Option 2.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for MediaStream's method prepareAsync() says:

**Prepares the player for playback, asynchronously. After setting the datasource and the 
display surface, you need to either call prepare() or prepareAsync(). For streams, you should 
call prepareAsync(), which returns immediately, rather than blocking until enough data has been buffered.**

I suggest to go with option 1.